# Is it safe to run a Kinect 360 cable in drywall?

Tags: electrical, data-wiring, low-voltage

Does anyone know if it's safe / compliant to run a [Kinect 360](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/browse/xbox-360/kinect) cable in drywall?  No extension, just the original cable, running a vertical 5-8 ft segment.

Comment: I remember seeing some rectangular "cable duct" type thing to jog up behind the drywall for some feet. If you installed that it'd probably be code, look cleaner and let you easily drop more cables down later. Though people sell [these things](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00390IT7O) (and [one with power](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B001PB7UVA)), so maybe whatever? LV cables still probably need to meet some flammability rating.

Answer (score 6):

Most likely not code compliant, at least - the insulation fire rating is what matters there - if you can read off any codes on the side of the cable jacket it might be possible to be more certain.

I'd suggest two boxes and a short section of conduit, as much because it will make it easier to replace when some new thing comes along in a few years, as for improved code-compliance/safety.

**Responding to comment:** - an electrical junction box at each end, not just "an opening" - I'd probably use EMT (electrical metallic tubing - the lightweight and cheapest type of steel conduit)  in between the boxes - use a size generous enough to pass your connectors through. Other types of conduit are probably acceptable, that's just what I would prefer for cost and effectiveness. While it might be acceptable to use the orange plastic low-voltage boxes, I prefer to stick with steel boxes.

Comment: Upvoted for conduit or a channel. This future proofs your A/V setup for the next hot gaming system and makes it easier to replace the current devices/accessories when they break.

Comment: The Kinect 360 doesn't have a power cord, it's powered by the low voltage cord (USB?) that connects it to the xbox.    
Ecnerwal when you say two boxes and a conduit, do you mean like just an opening at each end and some conduit behind the wall?  Does shielding the wires by the conduit make it compliant?  What kind of conduit is necessary?

Comment: @DX2003 Sorry, not familiar with video games. You said "cord", so I assumed "power cord".

Comment: @DX2003 this has actually changed depending on which revision of the hardware you have.  New ones are just USB, but older models did have a dedicated power cord.

Comment: Looking at HDMI cable specs, it appears that the average cable head is ~21 mm. Which means if you're going to use EMT conduit, you'll probably want to use at least 1" (26.6 mm nominal internal diameter). 3/4" EMT has a nominal internal diameter of 20.9 mm, which would probably be too tight to pass an average HDMI cable through. 10' of 1" EMT will run you about $7.50. Or you could use 2" PVC, which costs ~$6.50 for 10', and has a large 52 mm internal diameter (2" EMT is ~$17.00).